# what is the detail of template argument deduction process

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, partial-ordering

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Test{};

template<typename T>
struct Test<T&&>{};
```

Consider the above example, the standard says that the class template partial specialization shall be more specialized than its primary class template.

> Within the argument list of a class template partial specialization, the following restrictions apply:
>
> > The specialization shall be more specialized than the primary template.

To determine which is more specialized, the following rules will be applied to them:

> For two class template partial specializations, the first is more specialized than the second if, given the following rewrite to two function templates, the first function template is more specialized than the second according to the ordering rules for function templates:
>
> > - Each of the two function templates has the same template parameters as the corresponding partial specialization.
> > - Each function template has a single function parameter whose type is a class template specialization where the template arguments are the corresponding template parameters from the function template for each template argument in the template-argument-list of the simple-template-id of the partial specialization.

For primary class template, the rewritten function template would be like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void ordering(Test<T>)
```

And the rewritten function template for class template partial specialization would be like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void ordering(Test<T&&>)
```

According to the rule for "Deducing template arguments during partial ordering":

> The types used to determine the ordering depend on the context in which the partial ordering is done:
>
> > - In the context of a function call, the types used are those function parameter types for which the function call has arguments.
> > - In the context of a call to a conversion function, the return types of the conversion function templates are used.
> > - **In other contexts the function template's function type is used**.

> Each type nominated above from the parameter template and the corresponding type from the argument template are used as the types of P and A. If a particular P contains no template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction, that P is not used to determine the ordering.

Neither `function call` nor `call to a conversion function` is this context. So the bullet 3 works. That means, Take `void(Test<T>)` as P and Take `void(Test<T&&>)` as A, vice versa.

For this pair P/A, it is the case mentioned in [temp.deduct.type#10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#10), that is,

> each parameter type P<sub>i</sub> of the respective parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of P is compared with the corresponding parameter type A<sub>i</sub> of the corresponding parameter-type-list of A.

> Template arguments can be deduced in several different contexts, but in each case a type that is specified in terms of template parameters (call it P) is compared with an actual type (call it A), and an attempt is made to find template argument values (a type for a type parameter, a value for a non-type parameter, or a template for a template parameter) that will make P, after substitution of the deduced values (call it the deduced A), compatible with A.

Here, we only have one parameter in each function type.  So compare `Test<T>` with `Test<T&&>` and vice versa, such process are mentioned in [temp.deduct.type#9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#9).

However I argue here is that there's no relevant rule in the standard which says what's the detail about the comparison process. In other words, why we can deduce `T` from `T&&`(T would be `T&&`), But not the other way around. If I miss the relevant rules about the detail, please point it out. If there are indeed no such detail descriptions in the standard, where can I find the relevant technology about the detail of  template argument deduction process?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like what you've cited is a problem in what you're looking at, but it's already been noticed and fixed. In particular, you quote the following:

> Each type nominated above from the parameter template and the corresponding type from the argument template are used as the types of P and A. If a particular P contains no template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction, that P is not used to determine the ordering.

By N4800 (and maybe before--I haven't tracked down exactly when this was changed), this has been changed to the following (§[temp.deduct.partial]/4, 5):

> 4 Each type nominated above from the parameter template and the corresponding type from the argument template are used as the types of P and A.
> 5 Before the partial ordering is done, certain transformations are performed on the types used for partial ordering:
> **(5.1) — If P is a reference type, P is replaced by the type referred to.**
> **(5.2) — If A is a reference type, A is replaced by the type referred to.**

This effectively removes the possibility of deducing T as a reference type, because the type from which it is deduced can never be a reference.

Comment: Could you cite the link of the changed content that you quoted here. I will take a look at.

Comment: @jackX: I did: [temp.deduct.partial]/4 (and 5).

Comment: @jackX: Here's [N4800](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4800.pdf), in case that's what you need help with (but I'd download a copy, not view it online).

Comment: That rule still exists in the version of the standard  that I gave in the question. In my question , the `P` is  void(Test<T&&>) or `void(Test<T>)`, that rule does not say we can remove the reference that appear in template argument list. The meaning of that rule actually says that if `P` is `Test<T>&&`, than before the partial ordering, it should transform to `Test<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

In [temp.deduct.call] and [temp.deduct.conv], it mentions that

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument
> values that will make the deduced A identical to A.

I believe this rule is common knowledge so it is not mentioned in other sub-clauses (it is mentioned in the above two sub-clauses because there are exceptions in that two sub-clauses).

Comment: The question is how to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A. This detail does not mention in the standard.

Comment: @jackX "how" is not important. We only care the result. That is, if there exists a type that makes the deduced A identical to A, then that type is the deduced type, otherwise the deduction fails.

Comment: @jackX A potential problem is, what if there exist multiple types that make the deduced A identical to A? But so far I have not come up with such an example.

Comment: @xskzr That indeed a question here. Such as, deduce `T` from `T*`, we can find `T*` for `T` but not on the around way, why is this? This detail does not write in the standard.

Comment: @jackX When we deduce `P` from `A*`, there exists a type (`A*`) that makes `P` identical to `A*`; when we deduce `P*` from `A`, there does not exist any type that makes `P*` identical to `A`.

Comment: @sxkxzr I know that.  But I argue here is, when given A as int*, then when P is `int`, `P*` identical to `A`. My meaning is, the standard does not say when we have a P/A pair, what rule will we obey to find these template argument values. Or just the form that we can't make them equal. why `T` can accept any type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225920/discussion-between-xskxzr-and-jack-x).