# Why result1 and result2 have same value instead the <int> was missing from result2 line?

Tags: c++, function, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T add(T num1, T num2) {
    return (num1 + num2);
}

int main() {
    int result1;
    int result2;
    // calling with int parameters
    result1 = add<int>(2, 3);
    cout << "2 + 3 = " << result1 << endl;
     

    result2 = add(2,3);
    cout << "2 + 3 = "<< result2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**The `<int>` is missing but the code runs without any error**
Why so?
Is it necessary to add the  part?

Comment: It can infer that `2` and `3` are both `int`. Sometimes the compiler can't make this inference, and other times the only way to call a function like that (like a templated constructor) is for the compiler to infer it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the detail of template argument deduction process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917434/what-is-the-detail-of-template-argument-deduction-process)

Answer (score 1):

> Why so?

Because of [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

> In order to instantiate a function template, every template argument must be known, but **not every template argument has to be specified. When possible, the compiler will deduce the missing template arguments from the function arguments**. This occurs when a function call is attempted, when an address of a function template is taken, and in some other contexts:

(end quote)

This means that for your 2nd call expression `add(2,3)`, the template type parameter `T` is **automatically deduced** to be `int` from the function call arguments `2` and `3`.

While for the call expression `add<int>(2,3)`, you're explicitly specifying the template argument as `int` and in this case there will be no template argument deduction.